How to us the same server/client connection across multiple scripts/scenes?
I'm making a chess-like war game on Godot 4.2.1 (more details on the game in my GitHub repo's README file). Currently, I'm programming the multiplayer functionality.
A picture of two inscances of the game (red player on the left, blue player on the right).
So far I've got the chat working via RPC. There's a singleton script called "network.gd" that handles the creation of the server (which is always the red player) and the client (which is always the blue player).
network.gd:
extends Node

var peer: ENetMultiplayerPeer

func _ready():
    pass

# Make sure to properly configure the function to be called remotely
func _init():
    rpc_config("receive_message", MultiplayerAPI.RPC_MODE_ANY_PEER)

func create_server(port: int):
    print("Creating the server...")
    # Start as server.
    var peer = ENetMultiplayerPeer.new()
    peer.create_server(port)
    if peer.get_connection_status() == MultiplayerPeer.CONNECTION_DISCONNECTED:
        OS.alert("Failed to start multiplayer server.")
        print("Failed to start multiplayer server.")
        return
    multiplayer.multiplayer_peer = peer

func create_client(ip: String, port: int):
    # Start as client.
    print("Creating the client...")
    if ip == "":
        OS.alert("Need a remote to connect to.")
        print("Need a remote to connect to.")
        return
    var peer = ENetMultiplayerPeer.new()
    peer.create_client(ip, port)
    if peer.get_connection_status() == MultiplayerPeer.CONNECTION_DISCONNECTED:
        OS.alert("Failed to start multiplayer client.")
        print("Failed to start multiplayer client.")
        return
    multiplayer.multiplayer_peer = peer
    print("Connected to server!")

The the actual RPC calls handling the chat messages are made in the script "messaging.gd", which is attached to the scene "messaging".
messaging.gd:
extends Node2D

signal red_signal
signal blue_signal

func _ready(): 
    pass

func _process(delta):
    pass

func _on_send_pressed():
    send_message()

func send_message():
    var message = $Message.text
    var username = $Username.text
    rpc("receive_message", username + ": " + message)
    $Message.text = ''
    print("Message sent!")

@rpc("any_peer", "call_local")
func receive_message(message: String):
    if $ReceivedMessages.text == '':
        $ReceivedMessages.text = "> " + message
    else:
        $ReceivedMessages.text += "\n> " + message
    print("Message received: ", message)

func _on_host_pressed():
    emit_signal("red_signal")
    var port = int($Port.text)
    Network.create_server(port)

func _on_join_pressed():
    emit_signal("blue_signal")
    # var peer = ENetMultiplayerPeer.new()
    var ip = $Ip.text
    var port = int($Port.text)
    Network.create_client(ip, port)

So, the chat works - great! But now, when I try to send data via RPC in the actual game script (game.gd), it doesn't work. This leads us to the question: is it possible to use the server (created using a singleton script) in multiple scenes (or rather, multiple scipts attached to multiple nodes in multiple scenes scenes)? I'd like to send chat messages and game data between the players using the same connection - but the chat and the game board are in a different scenes.
Here's how I'm trying to send and receive data in game.gd:
A snippet of "game.gd":
# Funktion to send data
func send_data(positions: Array):
    rpc("receive_instance_positions", positions)

# A function to receive the data
func receive_data(positions: Array):
    print("Received instance positions:", positions)

A picture of how the Game scene is organized.
Here's a link to my GitHub repo.
Thank you so much in advance! I'm new to Godot so I may have misused some terms here and there - sorry for that! Hopefully you still understand my question.

It turns out I am dumb. This line caused the problem: rpc("receive_instance_positions", positions). It should obviously be rpc("receive_data", positions).
